# Syntax error when trying to format date using not delimited (%E4Y%m%d) format

Tags: google-bigquery, date-formatting

I get error  `Syntax error: Illegal input character "%" at [3:35]` when trying to use this syntax:

```
WHERE _TABLE_SUFFIX = FORMAT_DATE(%E4Y%m%d, DATE_TRUNC(DATE_SUB(date_val, INTERVAL 1 MONTH), MONTH))
```

Also the same error for the `%Y%m%d`. I'm trying to get for example 20210901 for the Sep 1, 2021. Could you help with that?

Comment: Use PARSE_DATETIME ---https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/datetime_functions#parse_datetime

Comment: The error was simply due to missing quotes around the format value